# A Glass Window in an Underwater City

Tags: cities, construction, engineering

In this scenario, an underwater city is a collection of domes interconnected by tunnels 17 feet wide and 17 tall.  The largest of the city's domes is 71,000 square feet in area and 137 feet tall.  The city is situated 500 feet beneath the surface.

When you descend deeper into water, it becomes imperative that you shrink the size of the glass windows to make sure that they don't crack under pressure.

In a dome of that size at 500 feet below sea level, how big and how thick must each window be?

Comment: I think you mean that the glass you use must be compressible, rather than that you have to shrink it?

Comment: Care to clarify?

Comment: When you say "shrink the size of the glass windows", I picture the window having its width and length reduced. Is that really what you mean, or do you mean that the windows get thinner due to being compressed by the water?

Comment: @Renan windows with a smaller contact area with the water.

Comment: stupid question, but -- why would you want windows down there? there's no sunlight anymore at such depth, so you'd just see blackness. I think your inhabitants would be a lot more satisfied with having good-quality screens on the wall where they can display whatever nature they want

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with worldbuilding, and is essentially an engineering type question having to do with glass and pressure.

Comment: What you've missed is that the interface between the window and wall is more significant than the size of the window.

Comment: Check out [aluminium oxynitride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxynitride), which might be a better candidate than glass.

Comment: @Aify we have tags specifically for designing structures, this question is fine for the site.

Comment: Unless the glass dome is super important to your story I honestly think it's a really bad idea to have. Talk about an Achilles' heel.

Comment: @subrunner  It gets dark at the mesopelagic zone, which is 660-3300 feet below sea level.  At 500 feet, you are still in the epipelagic, or sunlit, zone.

Comment: @JohnWDailey at a depth of 100m (330f) you've got about 0.5% of the light intensity on the surface (http://oceansjsu.com/105d/exped_briny/13.html). At 500f, you've got even less. Even in brightest daylight, that would give you a view that's about as great as an hour after sunset. Effectively, it would be comparable to living in North Alaska during midwinter (a few hours of twilight when the sun barely manages to reach the horizon, otherwise darkest night all day long).

Comment: @James I know we have tags for designing structures - but when I read this question, it isn't a structure-design question that's reusable. It's a very specific plot element of his single story that: a) doesn't even make sense to have and as such is likely never to come up for anyone else, and b) has a calculable answer through formulas and engineering, which means he can easily answer this himself with a bit of research.

Comment: @Aify You are assuming the user has a certain level of engineering knowledge that he may or may not have.  (I personally wouldn't know where to even begin answering this) None of us are an expert in all the topics on WB.  A glass domed habitat under the ocean is a perfectly acceptable (and not wholly uncommon) setting for us to build.  The depth details the user selected are his business and the answers it has generated could well be used by future people building an underwater dome to calculate what they need.

Comment: @James 1) Nowhere in the question does it say glass domes - it only says domes, and uses the terminology windows, which implies domes of other material with glass windows. 2) I'm not assuming he has any engineering knowledge. I simply did a couple quick Google searches and round relevant, useful information within 15 minutes. I have 0 engineering knowledge, and I could do it.

Comment: @Aify I am not saying your expectations aren't logical they are just not consistent with what the community as a whole has decided.  If you'd like to chat further, visit me in [chat]

Comment: @subrunner Well if the domes have lights on the outside, you could still see quite easily whatever they light up,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main issue here is the geometry of your windows; while 500' below the surface isn't *that far,* it's still a considerable amount of force over a large area. Your city, from a quick-and-dirty engineering standpoint, is just a series of pressure vessels.

So let's say you want a comfortable 1 atm of pressure inside the city. In reality, you'd want a higher pressure inside, to help counter-act the pressure on the outside. According to various groups, it looks like divers (breathing air) [should only go down to 50-60 m (~164'-196')](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_diving#Depth_ranges_in_underwater_diving), somewhere around 1/3 the depth of your city.

Engineering toolbox has a nifty [thick-walled pressure vessel stress calculator](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/stress-thick-walled-tube-d_949.html). If *any* of these stresses exceed the stresses of your "glass," your connecting tubes will break! Oh, we should also mention that there are different types of glass: borosilicate glass ([pyrex](http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=5bb651ca58524e79a503011b2cd8083d)), common fiberglass ([E-Glass](http://www.azom.com/properties.aspx?ArticleID=764)), [S-glass](http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=ccd3fcc24efb46a88a091f560487cee5), [soda-lime](http://www.matweb.com/search/datasheet.aspx?matguid=4bcaebf032014605885a9bb64010664a&ckck=1), even Star-Trek inspired [magnesium aluminate](http://www.trans-techinc.com/documents/magnesium-aluminate.pdf), and *many* others! Each of these have their benefits and weaknesses. Let's assume you're using a '[safety glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toughened_glass#Properties)', which is supposed to withstand 15000 psi of pressure. Using the tool from engineering toolbox, the minimum thickness allowed is: **4 inches** (otherwise the hoop stress is too much). This has no safety factors involved, so you likely want this thickness to be much higher, *at least 8 inches*.

You can perform a similar calculation for your domes.

Comment: 500 feet is almost exactly 150 meters, which is three times 50-60 meters. Did you confuse a unit somewhere?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, and I fixed it.

Comment: Don't forget transparent aluminum! First proposed in Star Trek, it is now a real thing: magnesium aluminate. Much stronger and harder than glass.

Comment: @PaulChernoch I added it, but I literally can't add every transparent material. The purpose of mentioning the many types of glass is to show that merely saying "glass" could mean one of many materials.

Answer (score 6):

For every 33 feet deeper in the water, the pressure increases by about 14.5 psi [[reference]](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/pressure.html). Also, the atmospheric pressure at sea level is about 14.7 psi [[reference].](http://www.britannica.com/science/atmospheric-pressure)

At 500 feet below sea level, the pressure would be

$$ \left(\frac{500}{33} \times 14.5\right) + 14.7 = 234.39~\text{psi}$$

Fully tempered glass in the US is generally rated above 65 megapascals (9,400 psi) in pressure-resistance, while heat-strengthened glass is between 40 and 55 megapascals (5,800 and 8,000 psi) - [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toughened_glass#Advantages)

As incredible as it seems, apparently, just a couple of inches should be easily strong enough.

Comment: Until that one person gets drunk and throws something at it :-P

Comment: A couple of inches long, wide, thick, or two inches in all of the above?

Comment: You've confused compressive strength with structural. Your calculation shows only that, for very small, thick windows the glass will not crush to powder. By analogy, consider that concrete has typical compressive strength in the 2,000 - 5,000 psi range, and 15 psi overpressures are considered adequate to destroy any concrete building other than a bunker.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Yes I was expecting something like that. I tried searching the internet for pressure _**versus thickness x area**_ type of unit for glass but there just wasn't any information on that.\

Answer (score 1):

The simpler solution would be to not keep the pressure in your city the same as the surface pressure, that way the difference between the water pressure and the air pressure would be minimal. The pressure difference between the upper areas (+137ft) and lower areas will be more pronounced than at the surface, but should be fine.

You cannot breathe a regular air mixture either, 500' is past the point of oxygen being toxic, and nitrogen will be causing problems too. There are a number of mixtures with helium that would likely be recommended.

The main reason you don't want to keep surface pressure is that any leak is going to cause a big problem FAST.

Granted, people coming and going will need to deal with decompression etc.